# Show / hide menu bar from command line on macOS Ventura

Tags: command-line, menu-bar

On macOS Ventura I can control the menu bar behaviour by going into system settings --> Desktop & Doc. It gives me four options for visibility: "Always", "On Desktop Only", "In Full Screen Only", "Never". Is it possible to switch between these options using the command line?

Comment: Probably, if you can find the key/value pair for `defaults write`. Is this going to be part of a longer script?

Comment: No, not really. I want to change the visibility of the menu bar based on whether an external display is connected.